# How store header x-access-token value after login, so that all routes can benefit, in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, token

i'm new in Express.
I'm trying to build simple login based on token system.
The idea is when the user log in, i set the token generated in the header, but the problem is that a i can't make it available for all routes.
Searching on google i found that a token login system, has no need sessions o cookies.
So the question is, How can i make the new header value available for all the requested?

Thank you in advance !!

My routes are:

```
router.get('/login', async(req,res)=>{
  res.render('login')
})
```

```
router.post('/login-verification', async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    const user = await Users.checkUser(req.body.email, req.body.psw)
    const token = await user.tokenGenerator()
    res.setHeader('x-access-token', 'Bearer '+ token);  //Here, where i sete the header value
    res.redirect('/')
  } catch (e) {
    res.send('login failed');
  }

})
```

```
router.get('/notes', auth, async(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req);
  res.render('notes',{
    auth:'Allowed'
  })
})
```

My middleware:

```
const auth = async(req, res, next)=>{
  try {
    const token = req.headers["x-access-token"] || req.headers["Authorization"];
    console.log(token);
    const decode = jwt.verify(token, 'Express')
    const user = await Users.findOne({_id:decode._id,'tokens.token':token})
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('Please Login')
    }
    req.token = token
    req.user = user
      next()
  } catch (e) {
    res.send('Please Login! ')
  }

}
```

My Model:

```
//Gen Token
userSchema.methods.tokenGenerator = async function () {
  const token = await jwt.sign({_id:this._id.toString()},'Express')
  return token
}

//validate User
userSchema.statics.checkUser = async function(email, psw){
  const user = await Users.findOne({email})
  const match = await bcrypt.compare(psw,user.psw)
  if(!user || !match ){
    throw new Error('Login Failed, please try again')
  }
    return user
}
```

Comment: Usually we  send token back to the client and client will set token in request headers next times. You can send token(s) as cookies too.

Comment: Could you provide a code example? res.cookie.auth?like this?

Comment: Just see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA0AIkjI85c
You will learn how to implement token based auth, correct.

Comment: But in my opinion ```setHeader``` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cookie parser to read cookies

```
 npm install cookie-parser
```

in your app.js file :

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

app.use(cookieParser())
```

login function :

```
  router.post('/login-verification', async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    const user = await Users.checkUser(req.body.email, req.body.psw)
    const token = await user.tokenGenerator()

    let options = {
        path:"/",
        sameSite:true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // would expire after 24 hours
        httpOnly: true, // The cookie only accessible by the web server
    }

    res.cookie('x-access-token',token, options) 
    res.redirect('/')
  } catch (e) {
    res.send('login failed');
  }

})
```

inside your middleware :

```
const auth = async(req, res, next)=>{
  try {
    let token = req.cookies['x-access-token'];
    if (token) {
      console.log(token);
      const decode = jwt.verify(token, 'Express')
      const user = await Users.findOne({_id:decode._id,'tokens.token':token})
      if (!user) {
         return res.redirect('/login');
      }
      req.token = token
      req.user = user
      next()
     }else{
       // cookie not found redirect to login 
       return res.redirect('/login');
    }
 }
```